# Relation between radii of incircle and excircle of a triangle : $r_{1}^{2}=d^{2}+2r_{1}r_{2}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

Problem :

Let $∆ABC$ triangle and $C(D,ED)$ excircle of triangle $ABC$ , $r_{1}=ED$ also $C(G,GF)$ incircle of a triangle $ABC$, $GF=r_2.$

$d=$ distance between centers of the two circles $d=d(D,G)$

> Then prove that :
> $$r_{1}^{2}=d^{2}+2r_{1}r_{2}$$

I know the center of the incircle can be found as the intersection of the three internal angle bisectors and The center of an excircle is the intersection of the internal bisector of one angle

But I don't know which relations I must use to prove the above relations[image]

Comment: Just a remark: the circle with center D and radius DE in your picture is the circumcircle or circumscribed, not an excircle.

Answer (score 1):

See [Euler's theorem for the triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry).